# WebMethods not working with VS2013

Tags: jquery, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, webmethod

What I used to do with WebMethods being called from jQuery in VS2010 no longer works with VS2013. Here is the page service code:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function Test() As String
    Dim strTest As String = "Testing"
    Return strTest
End Function
```

Here is the jQuery to call the method:

```
function TestService() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myPage.aspx/Test",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: '[]'
})
.done(function (d) {
    alert('success');
})
.fail(function (xhr, st, err) {
    alert('failed');
});
```

}

And as you can guess I am getting the failed alert always. This works perfectly in 2010. Can't find any thing new in the docs.

Comment: Forgot to add - the err is "Internal server error" which usually means the jQuery can not find the url you are pointing it to for the method. I did set a break point in the webmethod Test and we are not getting there.

Comment: The data in your ajax request isn't a string but an object. 500 usually means that you send incorrect data. Check the network tab to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks @GuyT - That worked - removed the data parameter all together and it worked. I could have also changed it to  data: '{}' If you make that an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `data: '[]'` isn't a string but an object. You have to change it to :

`data: {
     myproperty: 'value'
}`

or simply remove the data parameter.